# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

My Flutter application is **freezing on the splash screen** and I'm getting the following error log:
Getting this three plugin exception

It's working fine in other android version except for **Marshmallow** :

Already done this:

-Deleted all plugins and reinstalled with `flutter pub get`.
-Runned flutter clean and `flutter run`

```
    [ +183 ms] E/flutter ( 3672): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getStorageDirectory on
channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
[        ] E/flutter ( 3672): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 3672): <asynchronous suspension>

    [  +36 ms] E/flutter ( 3672): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on
channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)
[        ] E/flutter ( 3672): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
[        ] E/flutter ( 3672): <asynchronous suspension>

    [ +100 ms] E/flutter ( 3672): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on
channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
[        ] E/flutter ( 3672): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:157:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old plugin `e2e: ^0.6.1`, I updated it and it's working fine now